# How does golang implemented the convertion between []byte and string?

Tags: go

I am not able to get the answer by checking the generated assemblies:

```
    {
        a := []byte{'a'}
        s1 := string(a)
        a[0] = 'b'
        fmt.Println(s1) // a
    }

    {
        a := "a"
        b := []byte(a)
        b[0] = 'b'
        fmt.Println(a) // a
    }
```

Why the observed behavior is happening?
Is there a description of how go interprets these lines of code?
What does go compiler do for type conversion?

Comment: This is expected behavior in go. Are you questioning _why_ the observed behavior is happening, or are you looking for a description of _how_ go interprets these lines of code?

Comment: The [specification says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type): *Converting a value of a string type to a slice of bytes type yields a slice whose successive elements are the bytes of the string.* Notice that the spec says that elements of the slice are taken from the elements of string, not that the slice backing array is taken from the string backing array.  It's logically a copy operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't so much a compiler issue as it is a language specification issue. The compiler can and will do strange things sometimes--what matters here is that whatever machine code the compiler ends up spitting out, it follows the rules laid out in the language specification.

As mentioned in the comments, the [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type) defines the conversion of `byte` slices to and from `string` types like this:

> Converting a slice of bytes to a string type yields a string whose successive bytes are the elements of the slice.
>
> Converting a value of a string type to a slice of bytes type yields a slice whose successive elements are the bytes of the string.

In order to understand the behavior of your examples, you have to also read the definition of `string` types, [also in the specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types):

> Strings are immutable: once created, it is impossible to change the contents of a string.

Because `[]byte` *is* mutable, behind the scenes go must make a copy of the relevant data when converting to and from a `string`. This can be verified by printing the addresses of the 0th element of the `[]byte` object and the pointer to the first element of data in the `string` object. Here is an example (and a [Go Playground version](https://play.golang.org/p/C3tLa4AFy1V)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    a := "a"
    b := []byte(a)
    ah := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&a))
    fmt.Printf("a: %4s @ %#x\n", a, ah.Data)
    fmt.Printf("b: %v @ %p\n\n", b, b)

    c := []byte{'a'}
    d := string(c)
    dh := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&d))
    fmt.Printf("c: %v @ %p\n", c, c)
    fmt.Printf("d: %4s @ %#x\n", d, dh.Data)
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
a:    a @ 0x4c1ab2
b: [97] @ 0xc00002c008

c: [97] @ 0xc00002c060
d:    a @ 0x554e21
```

Notice that the pointer locations of the `string` and `[]byte` are not the same and do not overlap. Therefore there is no expectation that changes to the `[]byte` values will effect the `string` values in any way.

---

Okay, *technically* the result didn't have to be this way because I didn't make any changes in my example to the values of `b` or `c`. *Technically* the compiler could have taken a shortcut and simply called `b` a length=1 `[]byte` starting at the same memory address as `a`. But that optimization would not be allowed if I did something like this instead:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    a := "a"
    b := []byte(a)
    b[0] = 'b'
    ah := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&a))
    fmt.Printf("a: %4s @ %#x\n", a, ah.Data)
    fmt.Printf("b: %v @ %p\n\n", b, b)
}
```

Output:

```
a:    a @ 0x4c1ab2
b: [98] @ 0xc00002c008
```

See this in action at the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_qzl7gFWCBs).

Comment: Looking at the addresses of the slice and string doesn't really tell anything. Both are just header data structures that contain pointers to backing arrays (see [reflect.SliceHeader](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader) and [reflect.StringHeader](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StringHeader)). *Those* pointers would be more interesting.

Comment: @peter you are absolutely correct! Thank you for pointing that out. I have updated the answer using `reflect.StringHeader`. I verified that the [description](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) of `%p` for slices in the `fmt` package accurately describes what it is doing (i.e., printing a pointer to the 0th element of the array), so casting the slice to a `reflect.SliceHeader` is unnecessary in this example.